# android handover incoming call to other calling app

Tags: android, android-dialer

I have made my app default calling app but for incoming call i don't want to use my UI i want to handover that incoming call to system default app actually i am rejecting specific an incoming call from my default app but when other call come i want to handover it to default system app how can i achieve this i have seen apps on Play Store doing this i have gone through all of the `InCallService` methods but i couldn't find any method to handover calls to system calling app i tried this method too but its giving exception `no activity found`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_ANSWER, Uri.parse( "tel:" + number));
 this.startActivity( intent );
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 9 will have handover option so you can check maybe that can help you, more on: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call#handoverTo(android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)