# What is exactly "DIRECTION_UNKNOWN" for Call.Details class?

Tags: android, caller-id, callscreeningservice

### Background

I'm investigating how [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService) works (sample repository [here](https://github.com/joshfriend/GoFCCYourself), easier one [here](https://github.com/joshfriend/GoFCCYourself/issues/2), if anyone wishes to check out).

### The problem

I've noticed that for [callDirection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.Details#getCallDirection()) there is incoming, outgoing, and "[DIRECTION_UNKNOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.Details#DIRECTION_UNKNOWN)" :

> Indicates that the call is neither and incoming nor an outgoing call. This can be the case for calls reported directly by a ConnectionService in special cases such as call handovers.

I don't understand the meaning of this.

### What I've tried

I tried to see if I can cause normal phone calls to trigger it, but of course it's not as such.

### The question

What kind of special case is it? What is "call handovers" ?

Comment: A call handover is explained further [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call#handoverTo%28android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29). Short description is "A call handover is the process where an ongoing call is transferred from one app (i.e. ConnectionService) to another app." More details are included in the referenced documentation.

Comment: Can you please explain an example? A scenario? Is it a real phone call?

Comment: Does this make things clearer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134207/android-handover-incoming-call-to-other-calling-app?

Comment: @M.Abdeldayem Not sure. It means that an app handles the phone call (here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call#handoverTo(android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle) ) ? But then how come it's "unknown" ? It should still be incoming/outgoing, just from another app, no? Which apps can do it? What is the exact scenario?